# Wrong result for "ID" when using SELECT query mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have written a small piece of code to grab information from mysql database

the query I'm using:

```
SELECT id, title FROM mydb ORDER BY id DESC limi 0,4;
```

this code works perfectly on my local webserver but when I upload it to a public server
it works but the id associated with all the results is the same and is equal to some wiered number like 201454672 which is wrong.

I checked the database everything there is okay, the data in place and their ids are true
only select produces the wrong ID, everything else is okay

what the heck could cause this problem ?

Comment: Have your tried changing your limi to limit?

Comment: this is a typo mistake in here, it is not the case with the real code, anyway I have tried different simple queries to get the ID, they all produce the same wrong ID, I'm sure the problem is not from the query itself

Comment: Why don't post results from server database for `show create table mydb`? Did you check if there are any triggers defined on this table?

Comment: +---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| topic   | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date    | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| views   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+---------------

Comment: I don't know how to check for the triggers and what could possible bring them cause I never create any additional things

Comment: I tried re-creating the database again but the still have the same problem ... : CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visitors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;


INSERT INTO `visitors` (`id`, `count`) VALUES
(1, 270);

Answer (score 1):

As i can found in your query you made a silly mistake.Please correct it.
Change

```
SELECT id, title FROM mydb ORDER BY id DESC limi 0,4;
```

to

```
SELECT id, title FROM mydb ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,4;
```

If it is still not working then change Datatype of id to BIGINT and try.

Comment: this is a typo mistake when I wrote this question, unfortionatly that's not the problem

Comment: change Datatype of id to BIGINT and try.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the table structure. Verify the Size of id field.

It seems that the data in you live server has id value beyond its limit.

For data type and its limit, refer [MySQL Wiki](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: the size is int(11) it's okay because the ids stored are 1 and 2 and 3